# std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: visual-c++

```
C1EVMLogging::PublishError( NULL, 
                C1EVMLogging::C1EVM, 
                C1EVMLogging::Service, 
                C1EVMLogging::Failure, 
                NULL, NULL,
                L"realloc failed in CThreadMonitor::Monitor. Bytes requested: %d", 
                count * sizeof(HANDLE));
free(hArryPtr);

throw bad_alloc("realloc failed in CThreadMonitor::Monitor");
```

Hi I am trying to migrate a Project in Visual Studio 2008 to VS 2012 C++.I am curious to know why is this error showing up when I am trying to throw a exception with a string mesage.

Comment: Why did you delete the contents of your post?

Answer (score 0):

`std::bad_alloc` doesn't have a public constructor taking one parameter. The only public constructor is has is a default constructor taking no parameters.

Apparently, the implementation you use has a private constructor taking one parameter - but of course you can't actually use it, it being private and all.